# Why Visual Studio 2017 resets .NET Core web.config file while running

Tags: visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-1.1

I have been experiencing this weird issue since i have reinstalled my Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise.  I have a .NET core application with this following web.confg file.

```
 <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="true" />
```

As you notice, it uses the pass-through authentication.  But whenever I run the application through the IDE, it simply overwrites the above line and resets the forwardWindowsAuthToken to false. Which in turns, failed to work in the browser and gives 401 - Unauthorised error.  I have reinstalled the VS, reset the settings and even cleared my code repository many times but still no luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is, **you have configured launching project using IIS Express.** The web.config file values are required to run it properly. To change the values to use regular IIS, go to project properties and in the Debug tab select Launch: IIS, instead of IIS Express. This will still overwrite your values, but at least IIS integration will work.

[image: ASP.NET Core 2 Debug Tab]

You can safely ignore web.config values when you use .NET Core self-hosting, using .exe file, as the web.config is ignored when you self-launch the app that way.